# Error: clase no está declarada cuando se llama desde otra clase

Tags: c++

Este código me tira un error diciendo que `Ubicacion` no está declarado cuando lo llamo en `recorrido`. ¿Alguno sabe a qué se debe ese error?

Éste es el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Trenes {
private:
    int capacidad;
    int personas;
    int direccion;
    char *id;
    int ubic;

public:
    Trenes(int a, int b, char *x) {
        a = capacidad;
        b = direccion;
        strcpy(id, x);
    }

    Trenes() {}
    int getpersonas() {
        return this->personas;
    }

    void subir() {
        if (this->personas <= this->capacidad) {
            if ((20 + this->personas) < (this->capacidad)) {
                this->personas += 20;
            } else {
                int aux = this->capacidad - this->personas;
                this->personas += aux;
            }
        } else {
            cout << "no se pueden subir más personas";
        }
    }

    void actdire(int x) {
        direccion = x;
    }

    void bajar(int x) {
        int aux = this->personas * x / 100;

        this->personas -= aux;
    }

    void ubica(int x) {
        this->ubic = x;
    }

    int getdireccion() {
        return this->direccion;
    }
};

class Estacion {
private:
    Trenes ida;
    Trenes vuelta;
    int ide;
    int porcbajan;

public:
    Estacion(int a, int b) {
        this->ide = a;
        this->porcbajan = b;
    }

    Estacion() {}

    void agregar(Trenes x) {
        if (x.getdireccion() == 1)
            this->vuelta = x;
        else
            this->ida = x;
    }

    Trenes mandar(int b) {
        if (b == 1) { 
            Trenes aux = this->vuelta; return aux; 
        } else {
            Trenes aux = this->ida;
            return aux;
        }
    }

    void recibir(Trenes x) {
        if (x.getdireccion() == 1)
            this->vuelta = x;
        else
            this->ida = x;
    }

    void actualizar(int b) {
        if (b == 1) {
            this->vuelta.subir();
            this->vuelta.bajar(this->porcbajan);
        } else {
            this->ida.subir();
            this->ida.bajar(this->porcbajan);
        }
    }
};

class recorrido {
protected:
    Estacion sist[40];
    Ubicacion ubic[40];
    int cantest;
    int canttrenes;

public:
    recorrido() {
        this->cantest = 0;
        this->canttrenes = 0;
    }

    void agregarest(Estacion x) {
        this->sist[cantest] = x;
        this->cantest++;
    }

    void agregarTren(Trenes x, int num) {
        if (num >= this->cantest) {
            sist[num].agregar(x);
            Ubicacion nums(num, x);
            this->ubic[this->canttrenes] = nums;
            x.ubica(num);
            this->canttrenes++;
        }
    }

    void realizarmovimiento(int);
};

void recorrido::realizarmovimiento(int min) {
    for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < canttrenes; j++) {
            int     a = ubic[j].getestacion();
            int     s = ubic[j].getdir();
            Trenes  aux = sist[a].mandar(s);
            ubic[j].actualizartiempo();
            if (ubic[j].gettiempo() == 0) {
                if (ubic[j].getdir() == 1) {
                    ubic[j].actualizarnum(a - 1);
                    sist[a - 1].recibir(aux);
                    sist[a - 1].actualizar(ubic[j].getdir());
                }
                if (ubic[j].getestacion() == 0) {
                    ubic[j].actualizarnum(a + 1);
                    sist[a + 1].recibir(aux);
                    sist[a + 1].actualizar(ubic[j].getdir);
                }
                if (ubic[j].getestacion() == 0)
                    ubic[j].cambiardire(0);
                if (ubic[j].getestacion() == this->cantest)
                    ubic[j].cambiardire(1);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Ubicacion {
private:
    int numeroestacion;
    Trenes tren;
    int tiempo;

public:
    Ubicacion() {}

    Ubicacion(int x, Trenes a) {
        this->numeroestacion = x;
        this->tren = a;
        if (a.getdireccion() == 1) 
            tiempo = x; 
        else 
            tiempo = x + 1; }

    void actualizarnum(int x) {
        this->numeroestacion = x;
        if (tren.getdireccion() == 1) 
            this->tiempo = x; 
        else
            this->tiempo = x + 1;
    }

    void cambiardire(int x) {
        this->tren.actdire(x);
    }

    void actualizartiempo() {
        tiempo--;
    }

    int gettiempo() {
        return tiempo;
    }

    int getdir() {
        return this->tren.getdireccion();
    }

    int getestacion() {
        return this->numeroestacion;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Intenta subir la implementación de la clase `Ubicación`, ponla encima de la implementación de la clase `Recorrido`. mas o menos deberia quedarte:

```
class Ubicacion{ private:
    int numeroestacion; Trenes tren; int tiempo;
public: 
    Ubicacion(){}
    Ubicacion(int x, Trenes a){this->numeroestacion=x; this->tren=a;
    if (a.getdireccion()==1){ tiempo=x;}else{ tiempo=x+1;
    }
    }
    void actualizarnum(int x){ this->numeroestacion=x;
    if (tren.getdireccion()==1){ this->tiempo=x;}else{ this->tiempo=x+1;
    }}
    void cambiardire(int x){ this->tren.actdire(x);}
    void actualizartiempo(){tiempo--;}
    int gettiempo(){ return tiempo;}
    int getdir() { return this->tren.getdireccion();}
    int getestacion() {return this->numeroestacion;}


class recorrido {
protected: Estacion sist[40];
Ubicacion ubic[40];
int cantest;
int canttrenes;
public:
    recorrido (){this->cantest=0; this->canttrenes=0;}
    void agregarest(Estacion x){
        this->sist[cantest]=x;
        this->cantest++;
    }
    void agregarTren(Trenes x, int num){
        if (num>=this->cantest){
            sist[num].agregar(x); 
            Ubicacion nums(num, x);
            this->ubic[this->canttrenes]=nums; x.ubica(num); this->canttrenes++; 
        }}
        void realizarmovimiento(int);
};
void recorrido::realizarmovimiento(int min){
    for (int i=0; i<min; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<canttrenes; j++){ 
            int a=ubic[j].getestacion();
            int s=ubic[j].getdir();
        Trenes aux = sist[a].mandar(s); 
        ubic[j].actualizartiempo();
        if(ubic[j].gettiempo()==0){ if (ubic[j].getdir()==1){
            ubic[j].actualizarnum(a-1);
            sist[a-1].recibir(aux);
            sist[a-1].actualizar(ubic[j].getdir()); }
        if(ubic[j].getestacion()==0){ 
            ubic[j].actualizarnum(a+1); 
            sist[a+1].recibir(aux);
            sist[a+1].actualizar(ubic[j].getdir);}
        if (ubic[j].getestacion()==0){ ubic[j].cambiardire(0);}
        if (ubic[j].getestacion()==this->cantest){ ubic[j].cambiardire(1);}
        }

        }}}
```

Esto sucede porque a la hora de crear una instancia de la clase Ubicacion aún no la tenias implementada, es por eso que al subir su implementación cuando digas

```
Ubicacion ubic[40]
```

Ya el sabe a que clase te refieres.

Comment: listo, muchas gracias!

Comment: Ale , recuerda calificar la pregunta y marcarla como correcta si te ayudo, eso ayuda mucho a la comunidad a seguir creciendo, un saludo

Comment: Jajaja si muy importante esto ultimo. :)